# for in loop arithmetic

Tags: python, arithmetic-expressions

```
operation = ['/','*','+','-']
a =5
b= 2
for op in operation:
    output = a+op+b
    print output
```

Here the output I get is

```
5/2
5*2
5+2
5-2
```

but I want

```
2.5
10
7
3
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: `output = eval(str(float(a)) + op + str(float(b)))`

Comment: Why on earth would you expect e.g. `"5" + "/" + "2"` to be `2.5`? It's just a string, it won't be magically evaluated as a calculation (not to mention that, in Python 2.x, that calculation evaluates to `2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a dictionary that maps the symbols to functions that perform the operation, which can be found in the `operator` module.

```
import operator
d = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div }
operation = d.keys()
a = 5
b = 2
for op in operation:
    output = d[op](a, b)
    print output
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module:

```
a, b = 5, 2
for op in (operator.div, operator.mul, operator.add, operator.sub):
    print(op(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `eval` function:

```
print eval(output)
```

Note: `eval` evaluates anything in the string, even if its dangerous. Also, as you know your operators in advance, you can use the [operators](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) module:

```
import operators
operation = [operators.div, operators.mul, operators.add, operators.sub]
a = 5
b = 2
for op in operation:
    output = op(a, b)
    print output
```